# iPhone annotations cause app to act slow

Tags: iphone, annotations

When I load 500 annotations on map, app becomes laggy when moving a map, is there a way to solve this problem?
It's good when the map is zoomed and show 50 annotations, but when zoomed out to show all annotations, app is slow and it laggs when moving within a map.

Current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create location manager object
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // All results from the location manager
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    // Set accuracy
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    // Start updating current location
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;   // also MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid

    // Start off by default in some city
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = value1;
    newRegion.center.longitude = value2;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = value3;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = value4;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.annotations]; // --> self.annotations is array with 500 annotations
}
```

Comment: 500 annotations on an iPhone screen?  How is that even legible?  I solved this issue by reducing the number of annotations that show when zoomed out to less than 50.

Comment: I've seen apps that show thousand of annotations at once, but it is not laggy

Comment: What does your viewForAnnotation look like?  Do you have additional code to handle zooming in and out?  Are your annotations animated?